# How to save WooCommerce checkout custom fields to user meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I've created the following custom fields for the user meta using the [PODS.io](http://www.pods.io) Wordpress plugin:

- date_of_birth
- emergency_contact_name
- relation
- emergency_phone

I've added these fields to the WooCommerce checkout, under extra information, by using the following code in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'date_of_birth', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Date of Birth'),
        'placeholder'   => __('dd/mm/yyyy'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'date_of_birth' ));

    woocommerce_form_field( 'emergency_contact_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Emergency Contact Name'),
        'placeholder'   => __('contact name'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'emergency_contact_name' ));

    woocommerce_form_field( 'relation', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Emergency Relation'),
        'placeholder'   => __('wife/husband'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'relation' ));

    woocommerce_form_field( 'emergency_phone', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Emergency Phone'),
        'placeholder'   => __('xxxx xxx xxx / xxxx xxxx'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'emergency_phone' ));

}
```

Error checking:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['date_of_birth'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your date of birth' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Emergency Contact Name' ), 'error' );     
    if ( ! $_POST['relation'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter how your Emergency Contact is related to you' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['emergency_phone'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter the phone number of your Emergency Contact' ), 'error' );              
}
```

(Hopefully) update the **user meta** upon checkout:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( !empty( $_POST['date_of_birth'] ) ) {
        $dob = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['date_of_birth'] );
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'date_of_birth', $dob);
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emergency_contact_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['relation'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'relation', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['relation'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['emergency_phone'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emergency_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emergency_phone'] ) );
    }           
}
```

Unfortunately, the user meta custom fields are not updated when I checkout.

I can update the **order meta** custom fields with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['date_of_birth'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Date Of Birth', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['date_of_birth'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Emergency Contact Name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emergency_contact_name'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['relation'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Emergency Relation', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['relation'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['emergency_phone'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Emergency Phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emergency_phone'] ) );
    }           
}
```

However, we need the custom fields in the user meta, not the order meta.

**Can you see what is wrong with the code that saves custom fields upon checkout to the user meta?**

Thanks.

Comment: $userid is undefined in your example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

first, you should add your custom fields like this: (use `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter)

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields = array() ) {

    $checkout_fields['order']['date_of_birth'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Date of Birth'),
        'placeholder'   => __('dd/mm/yyyy'),
        'required'      => true, 
        );

    return $checkout_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
```

adding `'required'` and setting it to `true` will have the same effect with how you check if this field is set or not. (your "Error checking")

then in your `woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta`, the first parameter is not `$order_id` but the `$customer_id`. You should know too that the second parameter is `$posted`. `$posted` contains the `$_POST[]` data. Including your custom fields if you did the code above.

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id, $posted ) {
    if (isset($posted['date_of_birth'])) {
        $dob = sanitize_text_field( $posted['date_of_birth'] );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'date_of_birth', $dob);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That's just what I needed Reigel. The code works like a charm.

Comment: Reigel, I've posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719372/save-woocommerce-order-product-name-to-user-meta-custom-field).

Comment: Reigel not sure if you are still active, but if so, I am trying to modify this code to work when a user creates their account in the checkout process. I would appreciate if you can take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369817/save-custom-fields-to-user-meta-on-woocommerce-checkout-for-new-user-who-is-regi