# Can I somehow generate random Woocommerce user id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

the thing is that we want to generate random user ID during every user registration, since we would provide service and we need to issue random user ID to each of them. Would be best if user ID contains of 3 letter and 5 numbers. User ID needs to be shown on user dashboard as well. 
Stack: WP + Woo
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already creates unique user ID with every new register. You will need to add a custom user meta field with woocommerce checkout.

A sample guide from a quick google search point to the following

https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/

[How to save WooCommerce checkout custom fields to user meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705713/how-to-save-woocommerce-checkout-custom-fields-to-user-meta) - A hidden field could be added with a random string