# Save custom fields to user meta on WooCommerce Checkout for new user who is registering on checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added several custom fields to my checkout that only appear when a user is checking out as a guest for the first time. My checkout process requires that the user create an account to complete checkout.

I have added four fields using the `woocommerce_form_field` method and then I have tried modifying the code [provided in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709595/628770) to achieve what I want.  However, I have tried several checkouts, creating new accounts to check if the custom field values save into the new users' profile, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is one example of a solution I tried which did not work:

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['practitioner_license_number'] ) ) {
        $pln = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['practitioner-license-number'] );
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'practitioner_license_number', $pln);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2);
```

`practitioner-license-number` is my custom field added using the `woocommerce_form_field` method. I modified the code at the link above, so that the function runs on `woocommerce_created_customer` and then in `update_user_meta` I'm trying to pass the customer ID so that it saves the meta to the user profile that is created.

Would appreciate help trying to solve this. Most of the questions/answers on this subject assume that the user is logged in and already has an account, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you share, I think the problem lies in incorrectly passing to the `$_POST`, 
perhaps `practitioner_license_number` vs `practitioner-license-number`.

You can use the code below to see if your hook works, if the value is written in the database you know that the problem is indeed elsewhere.

It might help to share the code you used for the custom fields too?

```php
function action_woocommerce_created_customer( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) {
    $pln = 'test';
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'practitioner_license_number', $pln);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You're right. It was a minor error in my code. I fixed it now and everything is good :)